# Prepare exe for distribution

Tags: delphi

May I ask for some guidance please ?

```
Development machine – Windows 7  64bit
IDE – Delphi 7 pro (with 7.1 update)
Target machine for install – Windows XP (SP3) – NB this is the Win 7 Virtual Machine
```

I have built a small application, nothing more than a test app. A grid, a TADOConnection connected to an MS accdb file and a few TADOTables. Using Inno Setup I have also built an installer. I promise, it’s a very simple app.

When I install the ‘application’ on the XP virtual machine, everything goes according to plan, ie no error message and the installer completes. However, the application will not start. On the same XP VM, I have D7 installed and, here’s where it get’s weird, if the IDE is running, my application will launch without issue. If I close the IDE, it, my application, will fail to start again.

All I get is an hourglass for a second or two, and that’s it … no error message, no horrible MS dialog asking me if I want to send them info about this dreadful application, in fact I get no feedback whatsoever.

NB - Whether run from the IDE, or outside of the IDE, on the Win 7 machine, the application runs just fine.

I’m obviously missing something quite obvious, but I’m lost. I have even tried ….

```
program Project1;
uses
  Dialogs,
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  ShowMessage('Starting');
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

But I do not get to see the ShowMessage dialog.

I have read the many ‘Hello World’ tutorials. Gleaned a great deal of knowledge from generous SO contributers (thank you). But there must be another tutorial that teaches me what to do in order to ‘prepare’ my application for inclusion in an installer. I thought that if I unchecked the ‘Build with runtime packages’ in Project Options and then did Project > Project Build, I could build a file with everything I needed to run the application outside of the IDE.

May I ask if anyone could point me to the last piece of the jigsaw, please ?

Incidentally, is there a way to debug an executable outside of the IDE ? Perhaps some switch within Delphi that would produce a log file when the application starts … or tries to.

Thanks for your time ?

Regards,
John.

**EDIT** - I mentioned earlier that the file will run outside of the IDE on my W7 machine. I got this wrong ... it won't run unless D7 is up and running too. Also, I made a copy of the original folder with this file in and started messing with the Project Options switches. Suddenly, the new file is twice the size and runs OK. Problem ... I can't replicate whatever I changed on the original file / Project to know for certain what I have done is the cause / fix.

**Edit 2** - OK - the issue definately has something to do with the different file sizes. I have created a folder on the XP volume and dropped a copy of all of my BPLs from the Output directory in Win 7 Delphi install. Dropped my exe (the file that will NOT run outside of the IDE) in there, and also my accdb file too. Double click and ... Hey Presto - it runs. the grid displays my sample data ... beautiful.

Here's the thing ... Project > Options > Packages > Build with Runtime Packages is UNchecked. This should build me a LARGE exe file - (is that correct) but it builds a relatively small exe that needs the BPL's !!!!

Will do some more testing ...

Comment: I should have also mentioned that I have installed the AccessRuntimeEngine too on the XP volume too. John.

Comment: Are you using any trial versions of components. They sometimes are designed only to run from within the IDE.

Comment: @David Heffernan. Thanks for the idea, David. I've actually thought of that, as I have a EurekaLog trial. I have not unistalled this from the IDE, but I have disabled it from the Project. I think I need to take a step back and build another sample application adding one component at a time, and test install the file each time. I have an awful feeling, it's going to turn out to be something very simple to fix. PS apart from EurekaLog, the Win 7 IDE is a fresh install today.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your installer, especially if you're not using runtime packages. Delphi apps are indeed stand-alone; with few exceptions, they can be "installed" with a simple `xcopy`. It's hard to say what might be wrong; you could be using a thir-party component that makes some API call not supported on XP, or that does something strange in memory that XP doesn't catch. As far as debugging it, you can use remote debugging if you have TCP/IP between the development machine and the VM you're trying to run in. See the docs for `remote debugging`. It's a little rough to get working.

Comment: What windows event says? Any error?

Comment: @Ken White - Thanks, I'll check Remote Debugging out. Noticed something strange last night ... I made a copy of the folder and started 'playing' with the settings in Project Options. The exe file size in the new folder is now twice the size of the original and runs on XP without trouble. I need to read up on the Project Options too as I have no idea what I changed to double the exe file size.

Comment: @Hendra - no error message at all, that's why I'm so stuck. Thank you.

Comment: @Johnny: upvoted your first-time question for it's quality. Clearly you've been lurking here for a while and understand when and how to ask a question. Welcome to SO!

Comment: What is the name of your .exe file? Try renaming it to something random (with the .exe still). Sometimes people choose names like "control.exe" which clashes with an application already running.

Comment: SysInternals Process Monitor someties help to see what action was last before program choke up.

Comment: @Robert Frank - Thank you. I've learnt a lot from SO contributers and I'm grateful. I tend to look for answers first as I don't believe I would be the first to come across a problem.

Comment: @Arioch 'The - Thanks will check this out. But I have somewhat of a little bit of success over the last hour. Will update the main post with some info.

Comment: @mj2008 - Thanks, the exe file name was just the default Project1.exe. But it makes no difference if I rename it to say ... Johnny.exe it still won't run unless I run it from the new folder with the BPL's in.

Comment: @Ken White - PS you're right, the installer is not the problem as I am just copying and pasting the file between W7 and XP now with the same results. Apologies for inferring the setup was at fault, I didn't mean to do that.

Comment: still very weird. If you deploy DLL-dependent EXE without DLLs (and statically linked runtime BPLs are just a case of that) then it would not run at all, Windows would outright tell it cannot find required DLLs. It morre loks liek some dynamic attempt at loading was made. And mayeb seom BPLs were found, wit hsame name yet different(obsolete?) content. Just speculating.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have your tconnection as connected in the ide.

That lets you see how things will look with real data within the IDE, but now when you run your application, it tries to connect right at the start, when maybe not everything is set up correctly yet.

One possible solution: leave the connection component disconnected, and connect at a later stage, for example via a "connect" button.

At least it will be easier to properly handle exceptions like that.

Comment: You get an exception in that case. Your app doesn't just disappear without warning.

Comment: Thanks Wouter, but no. I build the connection string and turn it on in FormCreate. The times when I have made this mistake I get an exception as @Ken White mentioned.

Comment: @Ken he might have the connection, but it might go silent, if VCL not initialized yet and connection just could not show GUI window.

Try rasing exception in unit initialization section for example.

Comment: @Arioch'The: Except that the VCL's exception handler is set up long before it gets to the point of streaming components from the .DFM, so that's not possible. There's no indication that a DB connection is being set up in an initialization section.